# What is the device Barry (The Flash) has on his chest in the Supergirl crossover?

Tags: arrowverse, the-flash, supergirl

I watched the crossover between Supergirl and The Flash and as probably all of you also did, noticed a device we hadn't really seen before on Barry's chest.

I can only assume it has something to do with the blueprints he got from Wells but we haven't seen that thing before.

Was The Flash in Supergirl a future version of The Flash or is it just because both series don't run simultaneously?

And the main question is what that device does for him? Anyone who knows this through any other sources? Comics, etc..

Comment: I am sure, answer will be "both series don't run simultaneously".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Supergirl* crossover aired way early, because of the difference in schedules between CBS and the CW. As I understand it, the crossover takes place entirely within a single *Flash* episode that will air tonight (I think) and the whole thing will be explained.

But the basic answer to your question is yes, the device Barry has is based on the blueprints he got from Eobard Thawne the last time he traveled into the past. It's a device that helps him gain speed in some manner. Thawne, as Wells, used a similar device to build up his own speed during Season 1.

Comment: I figured it would be explained in the near future, couldn't wait for the episode since it has been a question since I saw the crossover. Thanks for the answer!